# What is output buffering in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, template-engine, pug

I'm programming in node.js using the express framework. The default template engine in express is Jade. In the Jade specification there is a concept mentioned called [output buffering](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/jade.md#code). What exactly is happening when I use this?

Comment: You might want to post an issue at on jade about clarifying their documentation with better explanation of that they mean there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is referring to the fact that executing JavaScript code with an `=` in Jade adds the result of that JavaScript to the buffer--that is, the text that is returned after the Jade template is parsed. `-` also executes JavaScript code, but does not add its output to the buffer.